# diff btw PTSN and DSL?

Tags: design, isp, wan

I have seen **DSL** compared to **PTSN** (public switched phone network).

What are some of the major differences?

Is there anything about **this answer to a similar question** [https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-ISDN-PSTN-and-DSL] that is particularly right or wrong?

Comment: This question is very vague. Please provide more context or details.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin cheers for the reminder! idky I didn't immediately accept the answer given that I thanked the respondent; slipped my mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare those two. They are completely different things.

xDSL is a family of point-to-point line protocols which can transport just about any digital data over a few hundred meters to a few kilometers, especially various packet-switched or virtual-circuit network protocols.

PTSN is a generalized term for a circuit-switched, analog/digital hybrid network that can be global. It can be used with (at least) a dozen of different transport mechanisms with hundreds of variations.

Comment: "You can't compare those two. They are completely different things." --> exactly what I was looking for i.e. I'd seen them compared and, as a newb, didn't know if the comparison was valid.

Comment: "a dozen of different transport mechanisms" --> what are the most prominent of these?

Comment: I'm definitely no expert on that, so off the top of my head: several different analog systems (roughly: manually switched, hook switched, tone switched), numerous, probably proprietary multiplexes (mostly FDM), ISDN, ATM, SDH, SONET, ...